# How Do We Identify the Owner of a Window?

Tags: android

Suppose we have an Android device, and on that device are 1+ apps capable of creating their own floating windows (e.g., hold the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission). Plus, of course, there can be other windows that are not necessarily independently floating (`Spinner`, `Dialog`, etc. all create their own windows via `WindowManager`, just for display over an existing activity).

Given that I know from developer tools a pixel coordinate inside a window, how can I determine the process or app that created the window containing that pixel? IOW, how can I find out who to blame for the existence of a given window?

I thought that perhaps `adb shell dumpsys window` would have that information, but if it does, I'm not seeing it.

Note that I am happy to settle for a solution involving development tools. I would hope that determining this information at runtime would be difficult or impossible without special privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this option: `adb shell dumpsys window windows visible-apps`?

It prints the list of visible windows with the following fields for each one: 
`mOwnerUid`, `package`, `mFrame`, `mShownPosition`, `mIsFloatingLayer`, etc.

Comment: OK, that is working, as is `adb shell dumpsys input` (from an answer that somebody else posted, but then deleted for some reason). Thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare I deleted that post because I couldn't convince myself that it answered your question. For my own edification, what about it worked for you? Thanks.

Comment: @Cheticamp: Well, it's pretty much what you wrote. Basically, I needed a `dumpsys` entry that had both the frame and something (UID, PID, etc.) to identify the owner of the window. Given candidate frames, finding the one that lined up with the window to be identified is not that tough, and from there I can derive who actually created the window. In your case, I got both a UID and a PID, allowing me to cross-check that those matched. I haven't undeleted your answer (as that's your call), but IMHO it's a worthy answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for responding. In case it can be useful to someone, I have undeleted the post and added an alternate way of identifying the window.

Answer (score 3):

Running this command `adb shell dumpsys input` gives me the following output:

```
[...bunch of stuff...]

    6: name='Window{5e9310c u0 com.example.overlayservice/com.example.overlayservice.MainActivity}', 
    displayId=0, paused=false, hasFocus=true, hasWallpaper=false,
    visible=true, canReceiveKeys=true, flags=0x81810120, type=0x00000001, layer=21010, 
    frame=[0,0][1440,2560], scale=1.000000, touchableRegion=[0,0][1440,2560], 
    inputFeatures=0x00000000, ownerPid=4086, ownerUid=10083, dispatchingTimeout=5000.000ms

[...bunch more stuff..]
```

Since I am backing into this, I know that the app is "Overlay Service" that simply shows a system window. The "frame" information would bound the pixel and "ownerUid" would give more info about the owner. (I am thinking that this command is more than a disguised `dumpsys window` command that is not working for you.)

Although it is not exactly a "this pixel to this app" mapping, assuming that you are seeing the same information on your device, this technique can help to trim down the targets.

---

**Alternate**

The following is a more direct approach if you have access to the device or are on an emulator.

According to the documentation for `dumpsys` under the category of [Input Dispatcher State](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/dumpsys.html#dispatcher_state),

> **Input dispatcher state**
>
> The InputDispatcher is responsible for sending input events to applications. As shown in the sample output below, its state dump shows information about which window is being touched, the state of the input queue, whether an ANR is in progress, and so on.

Reading further:

> After touching the touch screen and running dumpsys at the same time, the TouchStates line correctly identifies the window that you are touching.

Specifically, the string "TouchStates: ..." will identify the window that we are touching at the time we run `dumpsys`.

So, we should be able to run `dumpsys input` and look for the string `TouchStates` and print the following few lines to identify the window. Here is my Windows command line:

```
timeout 3 & adb shell dumpsys input | grep TouchStates -A 5
```

And here is the output that identifies `Window{e3cd95d u0 com.example.overlayservice/com.example.overlayservice.MainActivity}'` as the window being touched.

> TouchStatesByDisplay:
>       0: down=true, split=true, deviceId=0, source=0x00001002
>         Windows:
>           0: name='Window{e3cd95d u0 com.example.overlayservice/com.example.overlayservice.MainActivity}', pointerIds=0x80000000, targetFlags=0x107
>     Windows:
>       0: name='Window{ef28ce5 u0 NavigationBar}', displayId=0, paused=false, hasFocus=false, hasWallpaper=false, visible=true, canReceiveKeys=false, flags=0x21840068
>   , type=0x000007e3, layer=231000, frame=[0,1794][1080,1920], scale=1.000000, touchableRegion=[0,1794][1080,1920], inputFeatures=0x00000000, ownerPid=1632, ownerUid=
>   10027, dispatchingTimeout=5000.000ms

If no window is being touched, then you will see `TouchStates: <no displays touched>`.

Answer (score 1):

From `adb shell dumpsys window`:

Window #3 Window{41b85d98 u10 com.example.app}:
    mDisplayId=0 mSession=Session{41bc2e38 10536:u10a10030} mClient=android.os.BinderProxy@41b064c0
    mOwnerUid=1010030 mShowToOwnerOnly=true package=com.example.app appop=SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
    mAttrs=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(395x110) gr=#55 sim=#20 ty=2003 fl=#20008 fmt=-3}
    Requested w=395 h=110 mLayoutSeq=1200
    mHasSurface=true **mShownFrame=[885.0,642.0][1280.0,752.0]** isReadyForDisplay()=true
    WindowStateAnimator{41d4d2a8 }:
      Surface: shown=true layer=91000 alpha=1.0 rect=(885.0,642.0) 395.0 x 110.0

---

It looks to me that mShownFrame variable holds the data you need to determine if a pixel is contained by a window.

Comment: I do not get `mShownFrame` values in my `adb shell dumpsys window` output, from a Nexus 5X running ODP3. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0):

> I would hope that determining this information at runtime would be
>   difficult or impossible without special privileges

The most recent Android release is heavily locked down to prevent malware spoofing "trusted" applications such as online banking applications.

Even knowing what other processes are running via the `/proc` filesystem is now restricted, so it seems unlikely you will be able to know pixel ownership without rooting the platform (that would be a back-door to get the same information as `/proc` would expose about the current foreground process).

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer the question. Could you consider converting this into a comment?